# using fitText to dynaically fit to percentage of width flex 4.6

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, dynamic, text

flex 4.6

I have a module that contains a border container with a  label inside. I am loading text dynamically and would like the text to fill the label to 100% width. I have found reference to the fitText function below but have no idea how/where to include this code.

I have also tried to use css. Can i use the padding & margin of the label to get a percentage width for the text?

If not can someone offer the code how to include/ call the function.

I am getting several errors/? in the fitText below as well, such as

```
Access of undefined property FormattedTextField
Access of undefined property autoSize
Access of undefined property text
Access of undefined property width
Access of undefined property width
Access of undefined property numLines
```

thx

Art

module

```
<s:BorderContainer x="27" y="19" width="404" height="67" backgroundColor="#111">
        <s:Label id="hlText" x="54" y="5" width="307" height="55"  fontSize="55" styleName="HeadBanner"
                 text="{Mytext.heading}"/>
    </s:BorderContainer>
```

fitText as per http://fld-as3-samples-cn.googlecode.com/svn-history/r29/trunk/NewsLayout/src/com/example/programmingas3/newslayout/HeadlineTextField.as

```
package com.v1
{
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
import flash.text.TextLineMetrics;
import flash.text.TextField;


/**
 * Changes the size of the text to fit a given width and number of lines.
 * Useful for news headlines that should extend across a full column.
 *
 * We need to know:
 * - which font family, weight, and style to use
 * - the max width of the headline
 * - the max height in pixels of the headline
 * - the max number of lines
 * 
 * Algorithm 1:
 * - figure out the N-width of a character that should work based on pixelWidth / numChars
 * - translate that N-width into a point size
 * - try the point size, if outside of tolerance,; 
 *   - if too wide, adjust down a point, try again
 *   - if too small, adjust up a point, try again
 *   - if too wide last time, too small this time or vice versa, stick with the too small size
 * 
 * Pixels per character (width-wise) is roughly 1/2 the point size, so that's a good starting
 * point. So to get a starting point size, divide the overall width by the number of characters
 * to get pixels-per-character, then double to get the point size.
 */
public class fitText extends FormattedTextField
{

    public static var MIN_POINT_SIZE:uint = 6;
    public static var MAX_POINT_SIZE:uint = 128;

    public function HeadlineTextField(tf:TextFormat = null) 
    {
        super(tf);
        this.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    }

    public function fitText(msg:String, maxLines:uint = 1, toUpper:Boolean = false, targetWidth:Number = -1):uint
    {
        this.text = toUpper ? msg.toUpperCase() : msg;

        if (targetWidth == -1)
        {
            targetWidth = this.width;
        }

        var pixelsPerChar:Number = targetWidth / msg.length;

        var pointSize:Number = Math.min(MAX_POINT_SIZE, Math.round(pixelsPerChar * 1.8 * maxLines));

        if (pointSize < 6)
        {
            // the point size is too small
            return pointSize;
        }

        this.changeSize(pointSize);

        if (this.numLines > maxLines)
        {
            return shrinkText(--pointSize, maxLines);
        }
        else
        {
            return growText(pointSize, maxLines);
        }
    }

    public function growText(pointSize:Number, maxLines:uint = 1):Number
    {
        if (pointSize >= MAX_POINT_SIZE)
        {
            return pointSize;
        }

        this.changeSize(pointSize + 1);

        if (this.numLines > maxLines)
        {
            // set it back to the last size
            this.changeSize(pointSize);
            return pointSize;
        }
        else
        {
            return growText(pointSize + 1, maxLines);
        }
    }

    public function shrinkText(pointSize:Number, maxLines:uint=1):Number
    {
        if (pointSize <= MIN_POINT_SIZE)
        {
            return pointSize;
        }

        this.changeSize(pointSize);

        if (this.numLines > maxLines)
        {
            return shrinkText(pointSize - 1, maxLines);
        }
        else
        {
            return pointSize;
        }
    }
}
}
```